# Psychological analysis of diary data

Tags: emotion, measurement, experimental-psychology, mood

I am using the app [Daylio](https://daylio.net/) and I have already get 160 days and over 300 records.
App itself has the ability to analyze data, very simple and weak. E.g, what activities take place together; how the mood differs with and without given activity.

I am well in statistics and data visualization, but I am missing *possible questions to ask* about this data.
And get interesting results about my psychology, conscious activity and unconscious inclinations.

I would be grateful for possible advice and suggestions!

Comment: I am not exactly sure what your question is asking for. Are you asking how to add statistical calculations into the app? Are you asking what you might want to add? Maybe this question is best asked by going to the app developers?

Comment: No,I would like to correctly ask psychological  questions to this data. Understand what can get interesting.

Comment: It sounds as if you have quite a bit of data to analyze/cross-reference to gain some helpful insight-is there a particular area of information topic you were most interested in? I have found that Daylio has been very helpful for mood tracking purposes thus far.

Comment: This question is soliciting (and receiving) opinions, which makes it off-topic for this forum.  Closing.

Comment: Perhaps you want to ask what kind of analysis typically deals with this kind of data?

Answer (score 1):

The questions to ask would be limited on the data set you have. From what i understand, the app allows you to track

- Time
- Mood
- Activity

These data points might give a direction on how to make your mood better, if you're in a crappy mood it can show what to do to get in the good mood. But that is not as powerful as you answering for yourself why does this activity give me a better mood.

Here's the question you might need to ask , not on the data but on the possible correlations that come up from the data.

```
 What should i have to believe, if an activity A gives, mood A.
```

Few interesting data points :

1. A data point where you get both desirable and undesirable mood from same activity.
2. A data point where your mood improved over time doing the same activity
3. A data point where you mood decreased over time doing the same activity

The above three data points should let you know that mood is not directly influenced by doing something, but by the subconscious meaning you derive from doing it.